# Print string using INT 0x10 in bootsector

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

I want to create `printl` function that allow me to print string in the `ax` register. I am in 16-bit real mode and I can not find any way to print a message. I using `int 0x10` to print a single letter.

I try pass argument (string to print) in `bx` register, then in a loop print letter by letter and then go back using `popa` and `ret`. My code didn't really work -- either it created a infinite loop or printed a strange sign.

If you know more efficient way to do it then it's not a problem. I would also like to ask about comment your code if you gave any

This is my code

boot.asm:

```
start:
    mov bx, welcome    ;put argument to bx
    call printl        ;call printl function in sysf.asm
    hlt                ;halt cpu

welcome db 'Hello', 0

include 'sysf.asm'
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0

db 0x55
db 0xAA
```

sysf.asm:

```
;print function
; al is one letter argument (type Java:char)
;
print:
        pusha
        mov ah, 0x0e
        int 0x10
        popa
        ret              ; go back

;printl function
; bx is argument of type Java:String
;
printl:
        pusha
        jmp printl001
printl001:
        lodsb             ; I was working with si register but i would like to use bx register
        or al,al
        jz printl002
        mov ah, 0x0e
        int 0x10
        jmp printl001 
printl002:
        popa
        ret
```

Comment: Awesome question, I don't have that much knowledge of assembly but I wish I did (Degree in CompSci).

Comment: Which assembler are you using? Your code won't work with TASM, it looks more like NASM, but `include 'sysf.asm'` doesn't work with NASM either.

Comment: sorry my mistake i use FASM not TASM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lodsb` instruction loads the byte pointed to by the DS and SI registers but you haven't loaded either with a valid value.  Since this a bootloader you also need to use the ORG directive, otherwise the assembler won't know where your code, and therefore the `welcome` message, gets loaded into memory. Try changing the start of of your program to:

```
ORG 0x7c00

start:
    push cs
    pop ds
    mov si, welcome
```

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. I get nothing printed out. The code of printl001 was find on internet and I dont understand it much

Comment: This example assumes that the loader is entered with `cs:ip` equal to 0:7C00h. This [is not necessarily true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701854/boot-loader-doesnt-jump-to-kernel-code/32705076#32705076) however, `cs` may be 7C0h.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation for BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H) int 0x10:

> Teletype output:  AH=0Eh, AL = Character, BH = Page Number, BL = Color (only in graphic mode)

If `BH` is not zero, it will write to a video page which is not displayed.  Unless, of course, you have flipped to display whatever page is in `BH`.  Probably you will want to modify your print function:

```
print:
        pusha
        mov ah, 0x0e
        xor bx, bx       ; BX = 0
        int 0x10
        popa
        ret              ; go back
```

If your output causes the screen to scroll, `BP` [might be destroyed](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm), though it should not cause a problem for your code because it preserves all the registers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm totally new to this and I'm not sure if this is the efficient way to do this but it works for me

```
print_string:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, [bx]
    loop:
        cmp al, 0
        je break
        int 0x10
        add bx, 0x01
        mov al, [bx]
        jmp loop
    break:
        popa
        ret
```

Comment: For efficiency, you could only `push bx` / `pop bx` (much more efficient than `pusha`/`popa`), and let the function overwrite AX.  Also, `inc bx` is more compact than `add bx, 1`. You could also save instructions inside the loop by putting the condition at the bottom ([Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)), although the `int 0x10` takes much more time than this loop body.  Still, it's about equal for total code size if you do it with an unconditional `jmp` to a load + `test al,al` / `jnz loop` at the bottom.

Comment: It's generally recommended to set BH and BL before using `ah=0x0e`/`int 0x10`, in case the code is used with the VGA in graphics mode.  ([I can't print out a character in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68670526) shows an example of setting them in a useful way).  So you could pass the pointer in SI instead of BX (enabling `lodsb` as a code-size optimization if you want, although slower on modern CPUs than `movzx` and `inc si`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the suggestions on optimization. Can you give a little more info on how to use BL and BH for VGA output?

Comment: I don't know much about obsolete legacy BIOS interfaces, especially in combination with use BIOS video-mode setting calls ([int 10h/ah=00](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm)), that's why I linked Sep's answer for an example of sensible values to pass.  See http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm for Ralf Brown's interrupt list entry which covers the general case and quirks of some real-world BIOSes.

Comment: Also, [wallyk's answer on this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30834054/224132) links the same docs and has some description.  Not sure if the BH page number is actually significant in all video modes, or if that might be BIOS-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

If, in your *sysf.asm*, you already had a single character *print* routine, why didn't you call it from within your *printl* routine?
Not that it matters, so read on...

### Writing a bootloader

BIOS loads your bootloader program in memory at the address 7C00h and the only register that BIOS passes on to your code is the BootDrive number in the `DL` register. There are no other registers that you can trust to hold whatever value you would hope to find there!

Now, if you don't use the `ORG` directive on bootloader code, then the assembler (FASM) will conclude that you want an implicit `ORG 0`. You need to setup the segment register(s) accordingly. The code in the *PrintString* procedure depends on the `DS` segment register. Its correct value will be 07C0h.
However, most people will prefer to start bootloader code with an explicit `ORG 7C00h` (if only to make it recognizable in an instant). In this case the `DS` segment register needs to be loaded with 0000h.

### Using the BIOS api

The BIOS.Teletype function expects the following arguments:

- `BL` GraphicsColor; this is only used when the display is in a graphics mode
- `BH` DisplayPage; the number of display pages depends on the video mode
- `AL` CharacterCode; the ASCII code of the character to display
- `AH` FunctionNumber; the number 0Eh (0x0E)

Because the `BL` and `BH` registers are part of the `BX` register, we should never use `BX` to address the string when writing this kind of *PrintString* procedure!

And because, when in a bootloader, the display will normally be in display page 0 of the text video mode, we can omit the `BL` GraphicsColor argument, but we should still set the `BH` DisplayPage. If we don't, then the characters could land on any of the alternative display pages or even nowhere at all.

### What I would like

> I want to create *printl* function that allow me to print string in the `ax` register.

A name like *printl* is hard to read! And a label like *printl001* really hurts my eyes! Better use something like *PrintString* that conveys what is its purpose.

There's no benefit in passing the argument in the `AX` register. `SI` is generally the best choice in bootloader code because it facilitates the use of the `lodsb` string primitive instruction. This can reduce the code's footprint. But note that it will be wise to use the `cld` instruction once to be sure that the direction flag is reset so that `SI` can increment the way we want it.

```
        ORG     7C00h

        xor     ax, ax
        mov     ds, ax
        cld                 ; So `lodsb` will increment SI

        mov     si, welcome
        call    PrintString
        hlt
; --------------------------
; IN (si) OUT ()
PrintString:
        pusha               ; Preserving all registers
        mov     bh, 0       ; DisplayPage
        jmp     .While
.Do:    mov     ah, 0Eh     ; BIOS.Teletype
        int     10h
.While: lodsb
        test    al, al      ; Test for the end of the zero-terminated string
        jnz     .Do         ; Not yet
        popa
        ret
; --------------------------
welcome db 'Hello', 0
; --------------------------
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Because this code must run in 512 bytes, it makes sense to preserve multiple registers using the 1-byte instructions `pusha`/`popa`. But if the program allows it, not preserving will shave off even those 2 bytes.

Below is an alternative way of passing strings that allows to not have to specify the address of the string explicitly, shaving off a further 3 bytes.

```
        ORG     7C00h

        xor     ax, ax
        mov     ds, ax
        cld                 ; So `lodsb` will increment SI

        call    PrintString ; -> (AX BX SI)
        db      'Hello', 0
        hlt
; --------------------------
; IN () OUT () MOD (ax,bx,si)
PrintString:
        pop     si          ; -> SI is the address of the message 'Hello', 0
        mov     bh, 0       ; DisplayPage
        jmp     .While
.Do:    mov     ah, 0Eh     ; BIOS.Teletype
        int     10h
.While: lodsb
        test    al, al      ; Test for the end of the zero-terminated string
        jnz     .Do         ; Not yet
        push    si          ; SI holds the address where execution resumes (here its `hlt`)
        ret
; --------------------------
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Be adviced: All this "shaving off" is fine in the one-time bootloader code where codesize is everything. It's not meant to be used in your everyday-coding.