# I can't print out a character in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, bios

I'm trying to learn x86 assembly. I'm trying to make a toy OS. I tried printing out a character that was inputted but it failed. Is there something wrong in the input? Or in the output? I have set `AH` to 0x0E and used `int 0x10` but it still doesn't work. Why doesn't it work?

Note: I'm very new to assembly, so if I got something wrong in the text or in the code, please don't say how dumb I am.

```
char:
    db 0
mov ah, 0
int 0x16

mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, [char]
int 0x10

jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: The machine starts executing your program from the beginning.  What do you think happens when it executes `db 0`?  Do not put data into the path of execution.  Also, writing boot loaders is not a good way to start with assembly programming.  There are too many things to get wrong and too many weird restrictions.  Consider writing COM-type DOS programs instead if you are hellbent on learning 16 bit x86 assembly.

Comment: You may find http://www.independent-software.com/operating-system-development.html useful for your bootsector development.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> char:
>     db 0
> mov ah, 0
> ```

In assembly, you need to store the data out of the way of the executing code. In this bootloader, execution started at the top where you placed a data item. The CPU will try to interpret it as an instruction but it will fail (most of the time).

> I tried printing out a character that was inputted

Once you receive the character as input, you still need to actually store it in the memory labeled *char*. If you don't, then the instruction `mov al, [char]` won't have anything useful to fetch!

Please note that in a bootloader, you are responsible to setup the segment registers. Your code depends on a correct `DS` segment register. Because you didn't use an `ORG` directive, the correct value for `DS` will be 0x07C0.

And the BIOS.Teletype function 0x0E has additional parameters in `BH` and `BL`. Don't ignore these.

```
mov ax, 0x07C0
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 0       ; BIOS.GetKeyboardKey
int 0x16        ; -> AL charactercode, AH scancode
mov [char], al

mov bx, 0x0007  ; BH is DisplayPage (0), BL is GraphicsColor (White)
mov ah, 0x0E    ; BIOS.Teletype
mov al, [char]
int 0x10

jmp $

char:   db 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Answer (score 0):

its awesome that you are getting started with assembly, and it can be quite overwhelming, but anyway, I have prepared a super simple "Hello, World!" Boot loader that should help make more sense to you :p

boot.asm:

```
org    0x7C00                 ; BIOS loads our program at this address
bits   16                     ; We're working at 16-bit mode here

_start:
  cli                         ; Disable all interrupts
  mov  si, msg                ; SI now points to our message
  mov  ah, 0x0E               ; Indicate to the BIOS we're going to print chars
.loop lodsb                   ; Loads SI into AL and increments SI [next char]
  or   al, al                 ; Checks if the end of the string
  jz   halt                   ; jump to halt if the end
  int  0x10                   ; Otherwise, call interrupt for printing characters
  jmp  .loop                  ; Next iteration of the loop

halt:  hlt                    ; CPU command to halt the execution
msg:   db "Hello, World!", 0  ; Our message that we want to print

;; Magic numbers
times 510-($-$$) db 0         ; Aligning 512 bytes to take up initial boot sector
dw 0xAA55                     ; Magic multiboot number
```

I hope this helps you understand a bit more about assembly, and I hope it makes you want to learn more. :p

Comment: [`test al,al` is a better choice than `or al,al`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806/224132) - don't promote that obsolete inefficient idiom.  Also, you can put `hlt` in a loop instead of disabling interrupts so ctrl+alt+del would still work on real hardware.  (Because the keyboard interrupt handler can still run.)

Comment: I was just trying to make a nice, simple and helpful example, that could help him get on his feet. This is exactly why I don't like stack overflow, because there is always going to be people that aren't necessarily to help, but just to dispute arguments. @PeterCordes

Comment: I'm trying to help *you* improve your example.  You can [edit] your answer, and comments are for suggesting improvements.  Sorry about the phrasing of my first sentence, though; the tone was harsher than it needed to be.  Stamping out the use of `or al,al` is a bit of a personal mission of mine I guess, and I don't have anything against people who unfortunately picked it up from other example apparently dating back to 8080 like I explained in my answer that I linked.

Comment: It's a pretty good answer overall, just a couple minor tweaks would make it worthy of an upvote, IMO.   (Although there are several examples like this on other SO Q&As.)

Comment: Also, "multiboot" is a separate thing.  0xAA55 is the BIOS MBR magic number, not multiboot.  [Multiboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiboot_specification) is a standard format for kernel images that can be recognized and loaded *by* a bootloader such as GRUB, not for the BIOS to recognize a bootloader.

Comment: Also, you never set `ds` = 0 to match your ORG setting; some BIOSes don't start the bootloader with DS base = 0, so it's a good idea to always set it manually before using absolute addresses.  Your example will work fine on some machines, I assume including qemu or BOCHS, but could fail on some real-world machines so it's maybe not useful to "simplify" by leaving out things like that. See Michael Petch's [general tips for bootloader development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/224132).